# Shepherd-tour Javascript: Correct way of ending a tour

Tags: javascript

Shepherd is a tour library

http://github.hubspot.com/shepherd/docs/welcome/

I followed the docs and get it running okay.

But what is the correct way to end a tour? If we get into `complete` or `cancel` event, the tour is removed, but all the class and markup (shepherd's css) that was added is still in the HTML. Is there a official way to properly end a tour, or I have to manually remove them

Comment: Can you use distroy method ?

Comment: @sandyJoshi: The destroy does not work. Also it is the method of a step, not a tour